# Multiplying using assembly 8086 in DOSBOX

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am trying to do a basic multiplication but I keep getting errors and I don't understand why. I know that I have to use "MUL".

Here is the code I am working with

```
POP AX 
MOV AL, [NUMB]
MUL 10H
POP AX
RET
```

THE ERROR IS : INVALID COMBINATION OF OPCODE AND OPERANDS    at MUL 10H

Comment: What did you try? What was the error?

Comment: 1) post you code. 2) post your assembler command line. 3) post the actual error message you're getting.

Comment: Reading documentation is usually more effective than asking questions: http://www.8085projects.info/post/Explanation-of-Instruction-set-of-8086-with-free-Sample-Programs-e28093-Arithmetic-Instructions3.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good example of Unsigned multiplication (MUL operand):

```
Inputting a 2-digit decimal number

MOV AH, 1       ;read first digit
INT 21H
SUB AL, ‘0’     ; convert digit from ASCII code to binary
MOV BL, 10
MUL BL          ; multiply digit by 10
MOV CL, AL
MOV AH, 1       ; read 2nd digit
INT 21H
SUB AL, ‘0’     ; convert digit from ASCII code to binary
ADD AL, CL      ; AL contains the 2-digit number
```

You have to read the documentations as well in order to understand what every instruction means and how it works.
Here is a good site to start learning assembly, has nice examples from every basic instruction
[Complete 8086 instruction set](http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_instruction_set/8086_instruction_set.html#MUL)  and [instruction set of 8086 with examples](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Explain_the_instruction_set_of_8086_with_examples)

Comment: @harold I have tried the above code and have looked at some websites but i cannot seem to apply it to my own code. I am not asking for the answer, just some help getting my head round it

Comment: @NeverEnding why am I involed in this? Oh well. Just observe that `mul` only takes an `reg/memory` operand, not a constant.

Comment: @harold because you were the first to reply? Thank you, its working now

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really late, but the problem is that you cannot multiply by an immediate value. You need to load that value into a register, then mul with that register as the operand. Like so:

mov al, [numb]
mov ah, 10h
mul ah

Also, I'm not sure what you are doing with the pop instructions, but it looks like  you are popping ax twice, which will leave it loaded with an unkown value. Did you mean to use the push instruction at the beginning?